# Getting error in linear layout

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-edittext

I am new to Android. I am reading official documentation of Android about linear layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
tools:context="com.example.hassan_microsoft.a2ndday18122017.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/to"/>
```

At this line => android:hint="@string/to"
it is giving error and not working as i want it to be worked.[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUWMo.png)

this preview (Picture1) should be the result but mine is giving out as this one as below (Picture2). [Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfkqR.png) What can be the problem.? Thanks.

Comment: change your edittext height match_parent to wrap_content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this make your `EditText` hight to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:hint="@string/to"
    />
```

And also 
You need Create a new string resource value in value **res/values/String.xml** like below code

```
<string name="to">To</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the value of @string/to in your `strings.xml`

1. Go to app -> res -> values -> strings.xml
2. Create a new string value called **to** with the string value, it should look like this::

   Sample App

   ```
   <string name="to">To</string>
   ```

A simpler alternative would be to just change your hint value to :

```
android:hint="To"
```